# How to proper draw in multiple windows in winapi?

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I was told recently that in `WM_PAINT:` message I should only use `BeginPaint()` and `EndPaint()` .

But what when I need multiple windows with bitmaps or drawings in my main window?
How should I manage this in proper way?

So far I was using this routines, that worked for me and was logic for me.
Is it wrong? What is the proper way?

Thank You in advance.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    // main window - that contains other sub windows
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(_hwnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(_hwnd, &ps);

    // a window that shows a 256x256 texture:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps_texture_256;
        HDC hdc_texture_256 = BeginPaint(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDS_DC_TEXTURE_256), &ps_texture_256);

            HDC hdc_tmp_256 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc_texture_256);
            SelectObject(hdc_tmp_256, convert_hbm_texture_256);
            BitBlt(hdc_texture_256, 0, 0, 256, 256, hdc_tmp_256, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            DeleteObject(convert_hbm_texture_256);
            DeleteDC(hdc_tmp_256);

        EndPaint(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDS_DC_TEXTURE_256), &ps_texture_256);

    // a smaller window that shows 128x128 texture:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps_texture_128;
        HDC hdc_texture_128 = BeginPaint(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDS_DC_TEXTURE_128), &ps_texture_128);

            HDC hdc_tmp_128 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc_texture_128);
            SelectObject(hdc_tmp_128, convert_hbm_texture_128);
            BitBlt(hdc_texture_128, 0, 0, 128, 128, hdc_tmp_128, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            DeleteObject(convert_hbm_texture_128);
            DeleteDC(hdc_tmp_128);

        EndPaint(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDS_DC_TEXTURE_128), &ps_texture_128);

        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Every window paints itself.

Comment: Every window will receive its own `WM_PAINT` message, and thus draw to its own `PAINTSTRUCT`/`HDC` managed by their own individual calls to `(Begin|End)Paint()`.  Do not have a parent window draw its child windows, only itself. The child windows are responsible for drawing themselves when they receive their own messages.

Comment: So, does it mean I have to make Callback Window Proc for every window that I am gonna paint to?

Comment: @Mateusz [A callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-wndproc), which you define in your application, that processes messages sent to a window. You need make Callback Window Proc for every window.